# How to label an enterprise's delivery Jira ticket

Tags: jira

To enable an easy progress-oriented view of the delivery to enterprise clients, some tags and labels should be set to each relevant Jira ticket.

How a commitment to an enterprise client should be labeled in Jira?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the enterprise delivery label: i.e: SG_delivery
2. If it is a commitment that is part of the original SOW, Check the 'high integrity commitment checkbox, and add the relevant commitment deadline.
3. If it is a new functional requirement, add the new_FR label.
4. Update the priority field, the highest will be a 'must-have'
   (5.) After the request will be approved by the product managers they will add the relevant fixed version. i.e. 'post phase 1 depots' to show that the ticket is part of the project scope. They will also add the 'fixed version' of the quarter that the ticket will be released in.